# Custom Method Call in Kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-tooltip

I am trying to customize the tooltip as follows,

```
self.updateChart = function () {
    if ($("#chart").data("kendoChart") != undefined) {
        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
        // the following line throws an error
        chart.options.tooltip.template= "#= myTooltip(value) # ";
    }
    chart.refresh();
}


function myTooltip(value) {
    return Math.abs(value.x) + " ,  " + Math.abs(value.y);
}
```

However I am getting the following error

> "Uncaught Reference Error:myToolTip is not defined"

Doing as follows work; however I would like to keep working on the above code that will give me more flexibility.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "#= myTooltip(value) # "
    }
});

function myTooltip(value) {
    return Math.abs(value.x) + " ,  " + Math.abs(value.y);
}
```

Comment: The message is telling you that `chart.options.series.tooltip` is undefined. What is `chart.options.series` and where is it coming from?

Comment: I have fixed that problem actually, then I have faced another issue and my question is updated

Comment: Did you define the myTooltip function above the Kendo chart function? Sometimes that's required.

Comment: @Vash, do you have any knowledge on the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144782/tooltip-with-multiple-parameters-in-kendo-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("#chart").kendoTooltip(
{
    content : '#= myTooltip(value) #'
    ...
});
```

Check the docs which have some good samples:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tooltip/api

Also check this example out:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tooltip/template

Comment: Do you have direct solution to my issue? I am quite new on this platform. I could able to make it work my code in viewController, but once I decided to move it modelcontroller, then it throws that error. See my updated question added what you recommended.